# How to get the source code from a web?

Tags: java, html

I am trying to get the HTML source code from a Web. I've tried by doing this

```
u = new URL(url);
URLConnection con = u.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
while ((line=in.readLine())!=null){
    a.append(line);
}
in.close();
contWeb = a.toString();
```

But when I execute this code this is the HTML code that I get

```
<head>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=/distil_r_blocked.html?Ref=/windfarms/durrazzo-albania-al01.html" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ga.233033467223.js?PID=14CDB9B4-DE01-3FAA-AFF5-65BC2F771745" defer></script>
<style type="text/css">#d__fFH{position:absolute;top:-5000px;left:-5000px}#d__fF{font-family:serif;font-size:200px;visibility:hidden}#collective57bfda9e,#friendshipeadab1a4,#degrees85b85925,#friendshipeadab1a4{display:none!important}</style></head>
<body>
<div id="distil_ident_block">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="display: none;">
<a href="BangJensen32676optimal.html" id="friendshipeadab1a4" rel="file">reserved</a>
</div>
<div id="d__fFH"><OBJECT id="d_dlg" CLASSID="clsid:3050f819-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b" width="0px" height="0px"></OBJECT>
<span id="d__fF"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I see the HTML code with Mozilla Firefox (via Ctrl+U) the code that I see it's quite different

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><link id="ctl00_Link1" href="js/jquery/skin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link id="ctl00_Link2" href="js/jquery/skin-vertical.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://forensics1000.com/js/15075.js" async="async"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.js" ></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.jcarousel.min.js" ></script>
<div id="blq-local-nav">
 <ul id="nav2">
 <li id="ctl00_liWindfarms" class="first-child selected"><a href="./">Offshore Wind Farms</a></li>
 <li id="ctl00_liVessels"><a href="vessels.aspx" id="ctl00_A3">Vessels</a></li>
 <li id="ctl00_liTurbines"><a href="turbines.aspx" id="ctl00_A4">Turbines</a></li>
 <li id="ctl00_liFoundations"><a href="support-structures-for-offshore-wind-turbines-aid268.html" id="ctl00_Afoundations">Foundations</a></li>
 <li id="ctl00_liNews"><a href="windfarmsNews.aspx" id="ctl00_A5">News</a></li>
 <li id="ctl00_liMarketAnalysis"><a href="marketReports.aspx" id="ctl00_A6">Reports <span class="new">(new)</span></a></li>
        <li id="ctl00_liDownloads"><a href="subscribers/downloads.aspx" id="ctl00_A7"><span class='subs'>Downloads</span></a></li>

        <li id="ctl00_liEquipment"><a href="equipmentFinder.aspx">Equipment</a></li>
        <li id="ctl00_liPorts"><a href="ports.aspx">Ports</a></li>
        <li id="ctl00_liContactUs"><a href="contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
        <li id="ctl00_liAdvertise"><a href="request.aspx?id=advertise">Advertise</a></li>

        <li style="float:right;" >

            <a id="ctl00_LoginStatus1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$LoginStatus1$ctl02','')">Login</a>
        </li>

        <li id="ctl00_liSubscribe" onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('Goals','liWindfarms','MainMenu');" style="float:right;" class="first-child">
            <a href="request.aspx?id=owfdb" id="ctl00_A2">Subscribe</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="ctl00_subnav">

    <li class=" first-child"><a href="windfarms.aspx">Project Database</a></li><li><a href="subscribers/owfdb/pipeline.aspx"><span class='subs'>Timeline Chart</span></a></li><li><a href="converters.aspx">Converters</a></li><li><a href="substations.aspx">Substations</a></li><li><a href="../offshorewind">Global Map</a></li><li><a href="widget.aspx">Maps For Your Website</a></li><li><a href="windspeeds.aspx">Wind Speeds</a></li><li><a href="powerdata.aspx">Power Data</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

The HTML code still goes, but it's way too big to paste it here.
Anyone knows how can I get the real content of the web? and why this happens? I'm quite lost

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Comment: Is the fault the OBJECT or is that expected?

Comment: The source that is being returned IS the HTML source. If you're looking for the actual source code, this is inaccessible.

Comment: But when I see the source code (via Mozilla Firefox by pressing Ctrl+u) it is different from what I get

Answer (score 3):

Content protection mechanism is in place on the site. You should fully replicate browser behaviour (incl. cookies, refferer, etc) to get the page.

Answer (score 0):

The `URLConnection` input stream cursor is at the start of the body, I don't know this is possible to get the heade with this guy or not, but you may need give hand of `Socket`, something like this

```
Socket s=new Socket("176.12.59.8",80);
s.getOutputStream().write("GET /index.html?param=value HTTP/1.1\r\n".getBytes());
s.getOutputStream().write("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2\r\n".getBytes());
//send other header requests, cookie, etc...
s.getOutputStream().write("\r\n".getBytes());
s.getOutputStream().flush();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
while ((line=in.readLine())!=null){
    a.append(line);
}
```

the problem(hard-work) with socket is that with socket you just connect to a address and specific port, and the rest of the work is belong to to you(about sending and receiving the data).

this is a low-level approach.

**EDIT**:Consider opening the `http://google.com/`, the first thing is that with `Socket` you only need to specify the target path and port you are trying to open, then using the input stream send the data in order that both client and server understand each other, here the protocol is HTTP/1.1.

the google ip is `74.125.228.41`

Okay now just try the following code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
```

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Sock {

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    String line=null;
    Socket s=new Socket("74.125.228.41",80);
    s.getOutputStream().write("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n".getBytes());//requesting the root
    s.getOutputStream().write("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2\r\n".getBytes());
    //send other header requests, cookie, etc...
    s.getOutputStream().write("\r\n".getBytes());
    s.getOutputStream().flush();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line=in.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }

  }

}
```

you send

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2
```

and the out put

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 25 Oct 2013 08:14:44 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: NID=67=cnvAQD2mzWXzNmbkv40u0Fjqh-hfhbbBsqbgHmNbzvdxkUWEcNGbzeva56UYuuNfSzVgKeM0AwH8_yfesWA4mpdOLKTVYyPzJrlhrn7be1HWVMMxU-QSUQGfbR6N_OKQ; expires=Sat, 26-Apr-2014 08:14:44 GMT; path=/; domain=.; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
X-Cache: MISS from pouyanazm_appliance
X-Loop-Control: 37.191.91.249 57B724E7913CDA261C464198106FF67D
Connection: close

<html>.....html content is here....</html>
```

The `URLConnection` does all the above thing(send-data as http) for you, but it doesn't returns you the header data, just the body.
you have 3 choices either use `Socket` approach(you need to implement the http) or override the `URLCOnnection` in order to get the header data to, or use a 3rd. party library that I don't know even one, you may search it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I'm quite lost with all the headers that are needed for the petition. Could you explain a little bit more how to obtain the HTML code of the website with sockets?

Comment: you need to study HTTP/1.1 protocol dude. then implement it via `Socket` there are to many headers in HTTP/1.1 and each one is used for a specific requirement, so I have to know what are you trying to do!? first get started with HTTP/1.1

Comment: OK, one thing more to write down on my to-do-list. I'm trying to get the HTML code of a website, to get the information that I want from that website.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot take a look at the source code unless you are talking about hacking into the systems. ;-) The code you see is HTML code - which might be 1:1 with source code, but you can't see any PHP scripts, J2EE classes, etc. I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but I was talking about the HTML code, not PHP or Javascripts or whatsoever

Comment: So, you got the source code. What did you expected to see? Your code does what you need.

Comment: I have as a result to my code some HTML that it is not the actual code of the website

Comment: Post your actual code then (edit question), so we can see the difference and advise.

Comment: Updated the question with the differences between the code that I obtained and the code that I get via Ctrl+U with the web browser

Comment: Are you sure you use the same URL ?

Comment: Yes, the url it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the content from inputstream of a url(like what you did in your program).I have tried to get the content by using your code its working.Can you please try to read content from some other url,if you can get the content then you have to analyse the url which doesn’t give the content.Your debug scenario should be like this

1.Check whether the content is loaded using ajax.
  2.Are they blocking the anonymous user.
  3.Content may be zipped.

Comment: I've tried with another website, and as you've said it works perfectly. My guess is that the website doesn't allow to get the source code automatically...